# Is socket id necessary while emitting?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

If am emitting from backend and socket id is undefined then will client side get the event that i emitted?

I have also seen that even if the socket id is undefined, client side still gets events but i am not sure how this works.

I am storing  socket ids in redis but sometimes i get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Socket Ids change everytime.

You could decide to save a particular room name in the backend, and use it instead of socket id.

Then fetch it on the frontend and send it to the backend with an emit.

Receive on the server with socket.on , and save it to use it, for example with `socket.roomname = roomname`